# XMLHTTPRequest Not returning

Tags: javascript, apache-axis

I created a java script to connect to my web service however I never return from the send method of my request:

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.overrideMimeType('text/plain');
    request.open("GET", url, false);
    request.send(null);

    alert("Complete");
```

I never see the alert. However when I step through my service it returns successfully so it has to be with this script.

Note: I can run the url from a browser, chorme or firefox tested, and I am able to get the response I want. I just cannot get it from js.

Comment: Shouldn't `xmlhttp` be `request`?

Comment: Are you running with the JavaScript Console open?  Any errors or warnings?

Comment: No errors or warnings. Also fixed xmlhttp to request and still no change.

Comment: Check the network tab in chrome dev-tools. Perhaps the HTTP request is hanging on the server-side

Comment: Checked and there was nothing there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My web service was not set up to receive HTTP GET request (REST based service). I was only set up to handle SOAP based requests.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is because of the *false* in request.open(), which means that the request is synchronous, so the rest of the script won't continue executing until the response has arrived from the server. Does the server return the response package? If it doesn't, you should try changing the third argument of the function to true, it should continue with the script execution then.

Check this link out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send()

Comment: I need it to be synchronous though because I manipulate the data returned onto my web page. Yes, the server does return the response package.

Comment: There might be something wrong with the server script then. Did you try printing the response package in the console right after send(). If that doesn't work, then it must still be waiting for the response.

Comment: It is correct right after the send. Which leads me to believe that it is not a problem with the server.